# Native Spinner Dialog (IONIC 3)

Tags: spinner, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I've already used the native spinner in some older projects before and it's worked fine. However, I recently started a new IONIC's project (V.3.5.3) and It's not working properly or I'm doing something wrong. I also noticed that Ionic's Team has changed its Native Spinner Plugin recently, but I don't think that's the problem.

Every time I call show funcion:

```
this.spinnerDialog.show()
```

It returns:

> WARN: Native: tried calling SpinnerDialog.show, but the SpinnerDialog plugin is not installed.
>   WARN: Install the SpinnerDialog plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-native-spinner'

And yes, the plugin is already included in `app.module.ts` in providers part.

And yes, the commands to include the plugin were executed:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-native-spinner
npm install --save @ionic-native/spinner-dialog
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You had included plugin into app.module.ts, however probably you didn't install it. Just execute that command, which you got - 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-native-spinner'

Comment: Yes, I did, and if a execute the command `cordova plugin list`, it shows that the plugin is included indeed. I've already reinstall the plugin and even created a new project, however the results were same.

Comment: Did you also install native-plugin via
'npm install --save @ionic-native/spinner-dialog' ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I followed the Ionic Instructions https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/spinner-dialog/. But unfortunately it didn't work =/

Comment: @PedroDurek Plugin developer is here! please try again install cordova-plugin-native-spinner plugin.. Seems I've fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, do this while we wait for the fix:
edit

```
 project/node_modules/@ionic_native/spinner-dialog/index.js
```

Change line 84 to this

```
pluginRef: 'SpinnerDialog'
```

It's a temp fix that will work.